# String added to start of current working directory instead of the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im getting the current working directory and adding more strings on top of it, when i add a backslash to the path, it adds it to the start of the stiring.

How do i stop this from happening?

```
print(os.getcwd() + "\aaaa\aaaa")

This prints # aaaa\aaaa\Desktop\Test\Tails

instead of #C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\technical-test\aaaa\aaaa
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this windows? What do you get when you `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: You need to double your \ to print it. print(os.getcwd() + "\\aaaa\\aaaa")

Comment: @Wilfried: Then why was the *second* slash getting printed w/o being doubled?

Comment: @ScottHunter My bad, maybe it's because I am on Uni :) And path used / and not \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when dealing with paths in python your probably want to use `os.path` and not manipulate strings by yourself.
to add parts to the path use `os.path.join()`

try:

```py
import os

current_path = os.getcwd()

new_path = os.path.join(current_path, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")

print(new_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r"aaaa\aaaa"))
```

or

```
print(os.getcwd() + r"\aaaa\aaaa")
```

both will print ,

```
C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\technical-test\aaaa\aaaa
```